# Cómo utilizar tildes y ñ con libpq-fe en c++?

Tags: c++, postgresql

Estoy usando visual c++ y la libreria libpq-fe que viene con postgresql.

Mi problema es que para las consultas, no puedo usar caracteres especiales.

Por ejemplo:

En esta consulta no me da ningún problema:

```
conn = PQconnectdb (stringConexion.c_str());
PGresult *resultado;
if (PQstatus (conn) == CONNECTION_OK)
{
    resultado = PQexec (conn, "select * from cliente where nombre like '%maria%'");
    ExecStatusType r = PQresultStatus(result);
    if (PQresultStatus(result) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK)
    {
        PQclear(result);
    }
    PQfinish(conn);
}
```

Pero si la cambio por:

```
    resultado = PQexec(conn, "select * from cliente where name like '%maría%'");
```

Me da el estado de: PGRES_FATAL_ERROR

He intentado con "unaccent", pero eso sólo me sirve para las consultas de SELECT, más no para las de INSERT.

También probé con libpqxx y tiene el mismo problema.

Por favor, si alguien puede indicarme si se puede y cómo usar tildes y ñ con libpq, le agradecería.

**Editado:**

Mi base de datos está con codificación UTF8, si yo ejecuto cualquiera de estas instrucciones de ejemplo directamente en el pgadmin, en la ventana "Editor SQL", se ejecutan sin ningún problema:

```
INSERT INTO cliente (id, nombre) VALUES (1, 'María Hordóñez');
SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE nombre LIKE '%maría%'
SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE nombre LIKE '%hordóñez%'
```

Pero, si cualquiera de esas instrucciones trato de ejecutarlas desde c++ con libpq-fe, me da el error antes mencionado (PGRES_FATAL_ERROR).

Por cierto, libpq-fe utilicé en windows y libpqxx utilice en linux; y en ambos sistemas operativos configuré la base de datos con UTF8, y en ambos casos me saltó el error.

Será que libpq no soporta caracteres especiales?

**Editado - Solucionado**

Al parecer, en este caso, la base de datos esta en utf8 y por ello nada tiene que ver. El problema esta en la librería (libpq), en la forma cómo codifica los datos antes de enviarlos a la base de datos.

Se debe especificar la codificación, lo raro es que no funciona con "UTF8", porque por ejemplo la **í** la envía como "0xed" y ese código no existe en los códigos utf8. Se debe especificar mas bien como "LATIN1" (al menos a mí me funcionó asi).

Libpq tiene una función para establecer la codificación de los datos

```
 PQsetClientEncoding(conn, "LATIN1");
```

Y el código quedaría así:

```
conn = PQconnectdb (stringConexion.c_str());
PGresult *resultado;
if (PQstatus (conn) == CONNECTION_OK)
{
    PQsetClientEncoding(conn, "LATIN1");
    resultado = PQexec (conn, "select * from cliente where nombre like '%maría%'");
    ExecStatusType r = PQresultStatus(result);
    if (PQresultStatus(result) != PGRES_TUPLES_OK)
    {
        PQclear(result);
    }
    PQfinish(conn);
}
```

Ojalá que esto le sea de utilidad a alguien más que tenga este problema.

Answer (score 0):

el problema está en tu BD, debes cambiar la codificación a UTF8 para que acepte esos caracteres.

este ejemplo es tomado de un libro de postgresql y muestra como crear una bd:

```
CREATE DATABASE car_portal ENCODING 'UTF-8' LC_COLLATE 'en_US.UTF-8' LC_
CTYPE 'en_US.UTF-8' TEMPLATE template0 OWNER car_portal_app;;
```

Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Esto es correcto, pero el problema empieza desde la instalación al escoger región, idioma, ubicación, etc

Comment: bueno como tal no trabajo con postgre por lo que no te puedo decir mucho pero debe tener un fichero de conf al igual que todo SGBD. Si puedes echale un vistazo a la doc de postgre. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/multibyte.html

Answer (score 0):

Cambiaría la línea:

```
resultado = PQexec (conn, "select * from cliente where nombre like '%maría%'");
```

por

```
resultado = PQexec (conn, "select * from cliente where nombre ~* '.*mar[iÃ-]a.*'");
```

En donde: `Ã-` equivale a: `í`, esto es de la conversión de **ansi** a **utf8**

Comment: para el caso de la ñ es: "Ã±": si usas VS MFC,

Comment: CString ansi(rf.c_str());
std::string result;
result.resize(rf.size() * 2 + 2);
memset(const_cast<char*>(result.c_str()), 0, result.size());
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, ansi, rf.size(), const_cast<char*>(result.c_str()), rf.size() * 2 + 2, NULL, NULL);
return result;